# Edit control text in custom toolbar is blank in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I've got Excel addin with a vba edit control on a toolbar. This has worked for a long time under Excel 2003-2010. But under Excel 2013, the text property is always empty regardless of what gets typed into the edit control. Code is similar to the code below.

If I load the Addin as an .XLS, it works. But if I save it as a .XLA and try that, then it fails.

```
Sub test()
    Set myControl = CommandBars("test").Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlEdit)
With myControl
    .Caption = Search
    .OnAction = "tester"
End With
End Sub

Sub tester()
  MsgBox "I am gonna serach for: " & CommandBars("Test").Controls(1).Text 
  CommandBars("Test").Controls(1).Text = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: To ask a perhaps obvious question, is it the 1st control on the commandbar?

Comment: Yes, It is the 1st control on the commandbar.